# Spark merge sets of common elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|  Package  | Addresses |
+-----------+-----------+
| Package 1 | address1  |
| Package 1 | address2  |
| Package 1 | address3  |
| Package 2 | address3  |
| Package 2 | address4  |
| Package 2 | address5  |
| Package 2 | address6  |
| Package 3 | address7  |
| Package 3 | address8  |
| Package 4 | address9  |
| Package 5 | address9  |
| Package 5 | address1  |
| Package 6 | address10 |
| Package 7 | address8  |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to find all the addresses that were seen together across different packages. Example output:

```
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id |                               Addresses                                |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | [address1, address2, address3, address4, address5, address6, address9] |
|  2 | [address7, address8]                                                   |
|  3 | [address10]                                                            |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, I have DataFrame. I'm grouping it by `package` (instead of grouping):

```
val rdd = packages.select($"package", $"address").
  map{
    x => {
      (x(0).toString(), x(1).toString())
    }
  }.rdd.combineByKey(
  (source) => {
    Set[String](source)
  },

  (acc: Set[String], v) => {
    acc + v
  },

  (acc1: Set[String], acc2: Set[String]) => {
    acc1 ++ acc2
  }
)
```

Then, I'm merging rows that have common addresses:

```
val result = rdd.treeAggregate(
  Set.empty[Set[String]]
)(
  (map: Set[Set[String]], row) => {
    val vals = row._2
    val sets = map + vals

    // copy-paste from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623014/772249
    sets.foldLeft(Set.empty[Set[String]])((cum, cur) => {
      val (hasCommon, rest) = cum.partition(_ & cur nonEmpty)
      rest + (cur ++ hasCommon.flatten)
    })
  },
  (map1, map2) => {
    val sets = map1 ++ map2

    // copy-paste from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623014/772249
    sets.foldLeft(Set.empty[Set[String]])((cum, cur) => {
      val (hasCommon, rest) = cum.partition(_ & cur nonEmpty)
      rest + (cur ++ hasCommon.flatten)
    })
  },
  10
)
```

But, no matter what I do, `treeAggregate` are taking very long, and I can't finish single task. Raw data size is about 250gb. I've tried different clusters, but `treeAggregate` is taking too long.

Everything before `treeAggregate` works good, but it's stuch after that.

I've tried different `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (default, 2000, 10000), but it doesn't seems to matter.

I've tried different `depth` for `treeAggregate`, but didn't noticed the difference.

Related questions:

1. [Merge Sets of Sets that contain common elements in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616010/merge-sets-of-sets-that-contain-common-elements-in-scala)
2. [Spark complex grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129486/spark-complex-grouping)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Why not do: packages.groupBy("packages").agg(collect_set("address"))?

Comment: @AssafMendelson because it will give completely different result than I need. Please look closer at expected result. If I would have grouped, I would get 7 different results, but I expect only three.

Comment: @AssafMendelson example: address4 and address1 belong together, even tho they belong to different packages, because address3 have been seen in package1 and package2. So all the addresses from package1 and package2 belong together, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your data as if it is a graph where addresses are vertices and they have a connection if there is package for both of them. Then solution to your problem will be [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) of the graph.

Sparks gpraphX library has optimized function to find [connected components](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components). It will return vertices that are in different connected components, think of them as ids of each connected component.

Then having id you can collect all other addresses connected to it if needed.

Have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/record-linking-with-apache-sparks-mllib-graphx-d118c5f31f83) how they use graphs to achieve the same grouping as you.